# Run BehaviorSpace for turtles-own variables

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

How to run behaviour space experiment for turtles-own variables ?
Also how to generate output in tabular form in the output box ?

Comment: this is two questions. Do you want the  sum or mean of the turtles variables or the variables themselves ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the mean, sum etcetera of the turtles-own variables use the form

```
mean [size] of turtles
```

if you want all of them it is a bit trickier I use something along the lines of

```
[(word who "," size) ] of turtles
```

it produces an assorted list. I hope somebody else has a cleaner solution but I fear that is the best one.